# call application command from specific mojolicious installation

Tags: perl, command-line, mojolicious

I need to call my own mojolicious command from command line, using specific mojolicius intallation (System version of mojolicius is too old, and I can't update it).
How can I do this?

something like:

```
$ ./kraih-mojo-97e88d1/script/mojo my_app/script/my_app my_command
```

will be great!

Comment: You could take a look at perlbrew which will install a local copy of perl into ~/perl5 and then install Mojolicious into ~/perl5 using perlbrew's version of cpanm. Alternatively, if you're happy with your system perl, then use local::lib (search CPAN) and cpanm to install just libraries into ~/perl5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For quick-and-dirty solution try adding `use lib '/path/to/kraih-mojo-97e88d1/lib';` statement to your `my_app` script and run command as

```
perl my_app/script/my_app my_command
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a similar thing to the answer by melhesedek, but without changing your code, try using the `-I` switch to the `perl` interpreter:

```
perl -I/path/to/kraih-mojo-97e88d1/lib my_app/script/my_app my_command
```

or you can use the `PERL5LIB` environment variable, which you could set in your local environment, or prefix the command, like so:

```
PERL5LIB=/path/to/kraih-mojo-97e88d1/lib ./my_app/script/my_app my_command
```

Also, I personally believe that the `lib` module is too magical for my taste. It's not readily apparent in every-day use, but it should NEVER be used in say CPAN code. Just fyi.